# get data in xml use id

Tags: xml, xpath

I have xml like this:

```
<section data1="DATA1">
   <data2>DATA2</data2>
   <info>
      <id value ="id">
   </info>
</section>
```

every section has only one info tag so info/id unique for section.
I can get info tag use XPath expression : section/info[id[@value="id"]].
but How can I get section tag, data1 and data2 use id?

Comment: i just can't understand your question

Answer (score 1):

For section node:

```
section/info[id[@value="id"]]/ancestor::section[1]
```

For data node you could then extend the xpath:

```
section/info[id[@value="id"]]/ancestor::section[1]/data2
```